# Proving that a sentence in first-order logic is not valid

Tags: undecidability, proof-techniques, first-order-logic

By the completeness of FOL, one can show that a sentence $S$ in FOL is valid, i.e. that it holds true in every model, by exhibiting a proof of $S$. Such a proof string is a certificate of the validity of $S$.

To show that $S$ is *not valid*, one can either exhibit a counterexample model in which $S$ doesn't hold, or find a proof that such a model exists, either of which would serve as a certificate.

However, do I understand correctly that while a "certificate of validity" will always exist, that "certificates of invalidity" **do not exist** in the general case?

In other words, that there can exist $S$ which are not tautologies, and for which a counterexample model exists, but for which one cannot actually construct a counterexample, or a proof of its existence?

This is not a question about the ability of FOL to formalize arithmetic (which Godel proved is impossible), but simply whether or not, in a very foundational sense, it is possible to prove counterexamples exist to FOL sentences in general.

Answer (score 3):

The completeness theorem states, in an equivalent form:

> If a formula $S$ is *not* valid, then there exists some model $\cal M$ such that $$ {\cal M}\not\models S$$
>   or, equivalently
>   $${\cal M}\models\neg S $$

This is simply the contraposative of the completeness theorem, as stated on e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem#G.C3.B6del.27s_original_formulation).

This shows that there is always a "certificate of invalidity" as you ask. This is still true if you ask for $\cal M$ to be countable.

However, obviously there is no procedure to **compute** $\cal M$, by a straightforward argument involving undecidability of Robinson's arithmetic.

---

Edit: To answer the question of how one might represent such a counter-model:

Unpacking the proof of the completeness theorem shows that such a certificate can be represented by a [Herbrand structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure), which are the syntactic terms of the language, possibly augmented with constants and function symbols, and recursively enumerable interpretations for the predicate symbols.

In general however, the interpretation of a formula cannot be decided by such a recursive enumeration (but it can be semi-decided).

Comment: How do you actually get a certificate from this though? What would a certificate for M look like, and how could you represent it?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I've added some explanation of what a certificate might look like. The crucial keyword is "Herbrand model". Everything is undecidable though, obviously, so I'm not quite sure what you would want.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly where in the process decidability breaks down. Is it that a finite-length certificate is simply not guaranteed to exist, period? Or is it that a finite-length certificate is guaranteed to exist, but that it is not possible to verify that it actually is a counter-model to your sentence? (I believe you're saying #2 here, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Regarding the Herbrand structure, I guess this is in general an infinite-length construction, right? You can make it finite length only in some cases, such as if the universe can be represented via some recursive algorithm.

Comment: The Herbrand universe is always "recursive", in the sense that it is countable and has a simple description (as a set of terms). But the equalities (or other relations) induced by the axioms need to be deduced from the axioms, and so are only enumerable and not recursive.

Comment: The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem says that any FO theory with an infinite model must also have a model for each infinite cardinal. So you will then end up with a proper class of models, most of which contain uncountably many objects. It could, presumably, be the case that a sentence is valid in the countable models but negated in some extremely large uncountable model. How would it be possible to show this with a finite-length description of a Herbrand structure?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem exactly says that this cannot be the case. There is always a countable refutation of your invalid sentence.

Comment: I guess my main point of confusion is, if this is true, then it seems an algorithm to decide invalidity would be to construct every possible string and check if it is a proper refutation of the sentence in question. This, however, would make invalidity semidecidable, which it is my understanding that it is not. What am I missing?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I think you are missing the fact that invalidity *is* semidecidable! The completeness theorem exactly says that the notion of truth is entirely captured by provability, unlike the situation in arithmetic.

Comment: Validity is semidecidable, but I thought the idea is that it's complement (invalidity) is not. If it were, then here would be a fully deterministic, *recursive* (not just enumerable) way to decide whether a first-order sentence S is valid or not: generate all possible strings and check whether each one is either a proof certificate of S or a proof certificate of the existence of a model in which S doesn't hold. If it is, halt and accept/reject. Otherwise, continue. But isn't this impossible?

Comment: Basically, I thought that the completeness theorem says: if a sentence is valid, there is a finite-length proof of it. If it isn't, no such proof exists. Thus the algorithm that searches for all proofs will only halt if one exists, otherwise it will continue forever. But if we are saying that a finite-length proof string for *invalidity* always exists, whether it is by specifying a counter-model or something else, then we can fully decide first order logic by simultaneously searching for validity and invalidity proofs, and our search will *always* halt.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula in first-order logic with free variables $x$.  If $\varphi(x)$ is not valid, then $\exists x. \neg \varphi(x)$ is valid.  Let $\psi$ denote the formula $\exists x. \neg \varphi(x)$.  As you stated, if $\psi$ is valid, then there exists a finite proof of $\psi$.

Thus, if $\varphi(x)$ is not valid, then there exists a finite proof that it is not valid: namely, the proof of $\psi$ constitutes such a proof.

Moreover, if $\varphi(x)$ is not valid, then there exists a value of $x$ (say $x_0$) such that $\varphi(x_0)$ is false, and in that case there exists a finite proof that $\varphi(x_0)$ is false (namely, the proof of validity of $\neg \varphi(x_0)$).

So, the answer to your question is "no; a certificate of invalidity always exists".

Comment: You are saying that if the formula is not valid, its negation must be valid? I am very confused here, as I thought that wasn't true.

Comment: What about sentences which hold only in some models, and for which the negation also holds only in some models? Consider some Diophantine equation which first-order PA is too weak to prove has no solution, and consider the sentence asserting that the equation has no solution. This sentence is not valid in first-order PA because nonstandard models exist in which it doesn't hold. But its negation is also not valid because the negation doesn't hold in the standard model.

Comment: @D.W. If you allow constants $a,b$ in your language, $a=b$ is a formula $\phi$, which is not valid, but $\exists x,\neg\phi$ is just $\neg\phi$ and is not valid as well. I suspect you are implicitly assuming that there are no constants or function symbols in your language.

Comment: @cody This assumption doesn't help, because it doesn't work for $\forall x, P(x)$ any better than for $a = b$. And without predicate symbols other than equality you have $\forall x \forall y, x = y$...

Comment: @cody, In the formula $a = b$, the free variables are $a,b$.  If $a = b$ is not valid, then $\exists a,b . \neg (a = b)$ is valid.  If $\varphi$ is the formula $a=b$, then $\psi$ is the formula $\exists a,b . \neg (a = b)$.  Take a look at my answer again? I think I handle that.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia, it looks like you missed the same thing cody did:  you missed my comments about free variables.  I'm  not saying that if a formula is valid,  its negation must be valid.  The negation of $\varphi(x)$ is  $\neg \varphi(x)$.  I'm not saying that if $\varphi(x)$ is not valid, then $\neg \varphi(x)$ is valid.  Rather, I'm saying that if $\varphi(x)$ is not valid, then $\exists x . \neg  \varphi(x)$ is valid.  See the difference?

Comment: Valid means that it holds in all models. $\exists a,b . \neg (a = b)$ is not valid because there are models in which there is only one object in the domain. Indeed, first-order logic cannot prove that there exist two objects (what would a proof of this look like?).$

Comment: Regarding the free variable thing, you can see here that for a formula φ with free variables X = (x1,...,xk), φ is valid iff ∀Xφ is valid. When we talk about validity we are asking a question about the universal closure of the formula. What you are doing is negating the formula to see if it is satisfiable. But this is kind of mind boggling because you then ask if the satisfiability sentence is valid, i.e. is satisfiable in *every* model - which need not be true! I may make another question just about this as it's a pretty subtle point about terminology in FOL.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia You're right, my last remark was mistaken.